# unsupported traffic-manager error when using "telepresence --swap-deployment" command

Tags: microservices, kubectl, telepresence

My command is:
telepresence --swap-deployment {project_name} --expose 8080 --namespace {project_namespace}

And the error msg is:
connector.Connect: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = unsupported traffic-manager version 2.4.0. Minimum supported version is 2.4.5

How could I upgrade the traffic-manager?

Comment: Did you check the official telepresence documentation? I found [this](https://www.telepresence.io/docs/latest/install/helm/), please scroll down to the **Upgrading the Traffic Manager** section.